# Unable to create a new column

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am Unable to create a new column to an existing table through Entity framework Core(Using code first approach).

Column Name is  `public String Place{ get; set; }`

Below is my existing Classfile:

```
 public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 StudentID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength (64)]
    public String LoginName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public Int64 Gender { get; set; }
    public Int64 Age { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "timestamp without time zone")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate{ get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "timestamp without time zone")]
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public String Place{ get; set; }  // new column
 }
```

Issue : System.InvalidCastException: 'timestamp without time zone' literal cannot be generated for a UTC DateTime

Screen shot attached for your reference

[image]

Comment: Your attribute is telling EF to create a column of type `timestamp without time zone` which is obviously not a thing. What do you expect those attributes to do?

Comment: Hi @DavidG,  I am new to this Project and as per my knowledge after upgrading .NET core 3.1 to 6.0 they added the timestamp without time zone condition in the attribute.

Comment: @DavidG [they are though](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: @CodeCaster Oh, PostgreSQL...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to fix the Issue ref :

I removed the timestamp without time zone for the static data.
after that my issue was resolved.

Comment: Please include your actual solution, not a link.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).